# Who commissions all of Dethklok's vehicles and buildings?

Tags: metalocalypse

In the show Metalocalypse, the band Dethklok often has these crazy vehicles or buildings. A lot of them are armed with weapons too. At one point, their mansion was floating in the sky.

I'm curious if there is an in-universe explanation for who commissions these things to be made? Who decides that they need tanks, helicopters, and floating fortresses?

My assumption was that their band manager Charles was responsible.

Comment: I asked this question on sci-fi/fantasy because a lot of the themes in the show are both sci-fi and fantasy.

Comment: I would agree with your assumption that Charles commissions it, but I'm sure he get's a good degree of input from the band members for things they want.

Comment: The band members come up with something crazy and start making demands, then Charles goes out for quotes.

Comment: If you find evidence of this, please make an answer :)